# Can't locate elements from a website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

Trying to scrape data from a business directory but I keep getting the data was not found

```py
name = 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4')[0].text
# Results in: IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I tried to use `WebDriverWait` to make the code wait for the data to load but it doesn't find the elements, even though the data get loaded to the website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


url='https://www.dmcc.ae/business-search?directory=1&submissionGuid=2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,50)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'searched-list ng-scope')))
name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4')[0].text

print(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pym-0 iframe"))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)



wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.searched-list.ng-scope')))
name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4')[0].text
```

**its inside iframe , to interact with iframe element switch to it first. Here iframe doesn't have any unique identified . So we used the parent div which had unique id as reference from that we found the child iframe**

now if you want to interact outside iframe use;

```
 driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://dmcc.secure.force.com/Business_directory_Page?initialWidth=987&amp;childId=pym-0&amp;parentTitle=List%20of%20Companies%20Registered%20in%20Dubai%2C%20DMCC%20Free%20Zone&amp;parentUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dmcc.ae%2Fbusiness-search%3Fdirectory%3D1%26submissionGuid%3D2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b" width="100%" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" height="3657px"></iframe>
```

Switch to iframe and handle the accept button.

```
driver.get('https://www.dmcc.ae/business-search?directory=1&submissionGuid=2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hs-eu-confirmation-button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#pym-0 > iframe')))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.searched-list.ng-scope')))
name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="directory_list"]/div/div/div/div[1]/h4')[0]
print(name.text))
```

Outputs

```
1 BOXOFFICE DMCC
```